# MyBatis! Passing multiple parameter to Mapper DAO

Tags: mybatis

I am trying to send multiple parameter to Mapper function defined in DAO implementation but unable to send more than 1 parameter in the case when parameter are not holder of any class.
I mean how can I modify the following code-

```
obj.getName(int a, int b);
```

In DAO implementation

```
public void getAllName() throws PersistenceException {
        SqlSession session = sf.openSession();
        try {
            session.selectList("getNames");         
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

I want to send a and b to query getNames.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using DAO implementation then you can do this by using a `HashMap`. Just add the key-value pair in `HashMap` and add it in function call and you can access it in the `mapper.xml` using "key".

Comment: You could use HashMaps, but I wouldn't recomend it.  MybatisDocumentation says -  Doing selects, updates, deletes with hashmaps "are powerful, they are also very verbose, not type safe and not as helpful to your IDE or unit tests as they could be.".  The alternative is type safe Mapper interfaces.

Comment: @Andy +1 for you. but I just stated one of the way to do it using DAO implementation and without annotations.

Answer (score 13):

Use a Mapper.

```
interface Mapper
{
     @Select( " select names from names_table where a = #{fieldA} and b = #{fieldB}" )
     List<String> getNames(  @Param("fieldA") String fieldA, @Param("fieldB") String fieldB)
}
```

The @Param tag allows you to specify what you can use to access the parameter in the sql map.  This example shows a @Select tag, but it works the same as xml.

then change your code,

```
public List<String> getAllName() throws PersistenceException {
        SqlSession session = sf.openSession();
        try 
        {
             Mapper mapper = session.getMapper(Mapper.class);
            return mapper.getNames("a","b");
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Read the [user guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf) for more information.